# Reverse engineering Apps using Xposed

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, xposed, xposed-framework

So I'm Working on an Xposed module that should fit multiple apps, The purpose of the module is to create Automate the creation of A group of modules for different apps, What I need to know is,  Is there a way to know All the methods that are called by a certain app during it's runTime like If I could make an Xposed module that would save the names of all the called methods in  A database that would be a great help or If you have anything in mind regarding the automation of the Xposed modules please point me into that direction. Finally the app's purpose is to show the user the power consumption of each method in an app and show which use more power than others that's why I need to automate the process so I can create multiple modules for different apps without having to go through all the codes of the other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is theoretically possible:

You can for example load the dex files of an app at run-time and examine every class and method and hook them. However this will have several significant drawbacks:

1. When hooking many functions in an app the execution is significantly slowed-down.
   Even on high-end device the users will not accept this. This will also increase the Android error messages about apps that are non-responsive because your Xposed module slows them down.
2. From my perspective the even worse problem is that the slow-down means of course that the CPU has much more work to do so that in the end you will drastically decrease the battery life by your Xposed module.
   So in the end your battery usage monitor app which uses the data governed by the Xposed module would have to show that more than 50% of the battery is consumed by Xposed and your module (just a raw estimation, can be up to 80%) because of the large number of hooked methods.

Method hooking is a technology that only works good if you just a few methods that are executed not very frequently.

Alternatively you can use it on special test devices for evaluating something (so it is not used on a regular device used every day). In this environment increased battery usage and slowed down apps are not very problematic.

Comment: It's just for A study I'm working on It shouldn't be released for the everyday user,  Thanks for the answer, the 2nd issue might actually be a concern but would it help if only applied the hooks for some tests then only chose a couple of methods to hook at a time to get more accurate results?

Comment: @khaledsabri If you only do it for one app and just for testing then I would recommend to use Frida instead of Xposed. The development speed is much higher due to dynamic JavaScript code update while the app is running instead of a device reboot every time you update the Xposed module.

Comment: Is it easy tot make a transition to Frida from Xposed because there's much work already done with xposed

Comment: So I finally reached to the point where I'm actually attempting to do this the reverse engineering went well but about the performance issues How many methods should I hook at once before I start noticing any delay because there a method in exposed called hookAllMethods which hooks all methods in a class I was thinking of hooking all methods one class at time could this cause issues ?

Comment: It is not really the number of methods you hook, it is more how many hooked methods are called per second. If you hook one method that is executed a thousand times per seconds you will notice that (also depends on the CPU of the used phone). Just try it out. If you are getting messages about apps not responding you know that was too much.

Comment: Thanks a lot again  it makes sense will try it out an dgive you an update

Comment: Hi agian, sorry for bothering you again but now that Everything is almost done I ran into one last problem I have the names of the methods and names of the classes in each package to access them from the xposed module I saved all the names in a json then saved to a text file, now trying to access the file from xposed always returns null unless it was accessed from a hooked app and the App had storage permissions, So I'm in a kinda of the chicken first or the egg I need the package names to hook the apps and I need to hook the apps to get the package names are, do you thing this is a dead end

Comment: @khaledsabri Because of the different context the code is running this can be tricks. Therefore Xpose has an built-in shared XSharedPreferences system dedicated for that purpose. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66037560/150978 I am not sure if you have to use it. You could also try to place the config file(s) in a different directory. `/data/local` or `/data/local/tmp` are usually good candidates.

Comment: Yes XsharedPrefrences is an option but I chose not to use it because it needs the preferences to be set by the app as MODE_WORLD_READABLE and this limits my research to below android nougat instead of android oreo and below