# My Xposed Module Can't take key and value From SharePreference but It Works When I put It in Xsharepreferences

Tags: java, root, xposed, xposed-framework

here i try to put key value setResult in "android.telephony.TelephonyManager"

XposeHook.Class

```
 XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.telephony.TelephonyManager", lpparam.classLoader, "getDeviceId", TYPE, new XC_MethodHook() {

 public void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable{
      XSharedPreferences pref = new XSharedPreferences("com.yuvi.pirate", "user_prefs");
      param.setResult(pref.getString("imei_val1", " "));
 }
```

MainActivity.class

```
 final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", 0);

 btn_imei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String trim = edt_imei.getText().toString().trim();
        editor.putString("imei_val1", trim);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

but after put random imei in editText and click on button btn_imei it create key "imei_val1" and value "which i write in editText" in Sharepreference but XSharePreference can't take that random key value which i put from Sharepreference

Comment: `getDeviceId()` is deprecated since API26. May be you are simply hooking the wrong method? See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId() Does it work if you use a static IMEI (instead of loading one from shared pref)?

Comment: I knw this thats why i use getImei too for replace imei with my sharepreference which use r put his own random imei  But whenerver i put imei in edittext box its add imei in my sharepreference "user_prefs" but main issue is that XsharePreference not take imei number from my sharepreference

Comment: Look at the [examples using XSharedPreferences](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=de.robv.android.xposed.XSharedPreferences) (especially [example 11](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=tianma8023%2FXMiTools%2FXMiTools-master%2Fapp%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Ftianma%2Ftweaks%2Fmiui%2Fxp%2Fhook%2Fsystemui%2FSystemUIHook.java)). Typically you load the preferences via `XSPUtils.getXSharedPreferences();` directly in `onLoadPackage()`.

Comment: Thanks bro its help me smthg more i will inform if its works or not

Comment: so lots of experiment now i see i have to make user_prefs Worldreadable!! thanks again for help

Comment: If you have found a solution it would be nice if you could write an answer and include the necessary code so that other developers can use it in future. Self-answering an own question is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

its not taking Sharepreference coz we can't read user_pref.xml after android SDK N (24) SO we have to make user_prefs.xml world readable !! so make sharepreference worldReadable and its solved

what you have to do make preference readable for worldreadable just go in targetSdk 23 or less than and them use Context.Mode_Worldreadable and now Xsharedpreference read your prfs file

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and include the code you use (especially where you make the pref world readable)?